# Connection to SQS from EC2 is lost from time to time

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Once a month on average, I lose the connection to AWS SQS from my java applications running on AWS EC2 machines:

> Received an UnknownHostException when attempting to interact with a service. See cause for the exact endpoint that is failing to resolve. If this is happening on an endpoint that previously worked, there may be a network connectivity issue or your DNS cache could be storing endpoints for too long.

With a root cause :
`java.net.UnknownHostException: sqs.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com`

I've checked my java cache DNS configurations, that are the default ones of the docker image `amazoncorretto:17-alpine`:

- `networkaddress.cache.ttl=30`
- `networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10`

Here is how I configure my SqsClient, using the AWS SDKv2:

```java
SqsClient sqsClient = SqsClient.builder()
                    .region(Region.EU_WEST_3)
                    .credentialsProvider(InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.create())
                    .build();
```

And how I consume message:

```java
ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = ReceiveMessageRequest.builder()
                    .queueUrl(queueUrl)
                    .maxNumberOfMessages(1)
                    .visibilityTimeout(30)
                    .build();

sqsClient.receiveMessage(sqsRequest)
                .messages()
                .forEach(message -> /*some processing*/);
```

As I use the default configuration of the `SqsClient`, I am using `software.amazon.awssdk.core.retry.RetryMode.STANDARD` that retries twice, with an exponential back-off starting at 100ms, meaning that I will retry for less than a second, so below my `networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl` configuration.

1. Should I only increase the number of retries ?
2. I have multiple applications connecting to a `eu-west-3` SQS queue, that are configured more or less in the same way. Shouldn't they all throw the `UnknownHostException` at the same moment ?

Comment: How long do you keep the connection before closing it?

Comment: The connection is not open _per se_, but I regularly poll the queue. Sometimes a poll throws an `UnknownHostException`

Answer (score 1):

I have occasionally experienced similar situations with the frequent calling of S3 APIs.

Regardless of the underlying cause, I would increase the number of retries. Exponential backoff starting with 100ms means you'll try twice in a tiny window.

Comment: I agree on that, but I find it surprising that the default configuration of the SDK does not properly handle this situation that happens quite often. And I'm also surprised that it happens only to one instance at a time.

Comment: @Raphallal I agree. SDK should properly handle this, but apparently, it's at the user's discretion.